# Dovecot can't connect to MariaDB when require_secure_transport is on

Tags: dovecot, mariadb

I have a Dovecot server that uses MariaDB for virtual mailboxes. The MariaDB server is on another machine in the same LAN.

We recently enabled TLS on the MariaDB machine.

Dovecot works fine when `require_secure_transport` is off, but fails to connect when we turn `require_secure_transport` on in the MariaDB configuration file.

The Error is:

```
Error: mysql(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx): Connect failed to database (db_name): Access denied for user 'db_user'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

This looks like an authentication error, but connecting with this same user and password works fine when `require_secure_transport` is off, so MariaDB is refusing the connection because Dovecot isn't using TLS.

The connect string in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` looks like:

```
connect = host=db0.mydomain.com dbname=my_db user=the_user password=secret ssl_ca=/etc/ssl/authority/authority.crt
```

The config file says:

> ssl_ca, ssl_ca_path - Set either one or both to enable SSL

Can I get more verbose details of the error? For example, if it's a TLS version mismatch, can I get that to show somewhere?

Is there a setting in Dovecot I need to change?

UPDATE: Adding `ssl_verify_server_cert=no` to the connect string in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` allows the connection to work.

So it seems to be a certificate verification error. But without more verbose logging, I'm not sure what it doesn't like about the certificate.

The certificate is signed by the CA in the connect string. It would be good to know what common name it is checking and also if Dovecot will use any of the SAN values for the certificate.

Comment: Are you specifying ip in connection string? What's in the cn if the cert? I would bet that this is the issue...

Comment: Is there a way to get more verbose output from the error, for example, what host name it thinks is being used to connect? I have also tried connecting from Dovecot with the hostname (FQDN) that matches the CN of the certificate that MariaDB has installed. I have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Is `db0.mydomain.com` the Common Name in the certificate?

Comment: @vidarlo yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work correctly by setting up a DNS server on the local network with records for the imap and MariaDB server's hostnames, and then setting `resolv.conf` on both machines to use it.

Dovecot now connects without issue with `require_secure_transport` set in MariaDB and `ssl_verify_server_cert=yes` set in Dovecot's connection string.

Without a more detailed error message for debugging, my best guess is that the TLS implementation ignores the mappings in `/etc/hosts`, and requires the use of an actual DNS server.